# Replace values by other table category

Tags: r, plyr

I`ve got these 2 tables

```
recordtable 
name  cat  value1  value2  value3 
jkl   A    1       2       3
jfu   A    2       3       4
eyr   B    4       3       2
...
```

```
categorytable_value1
cat  value
A    1.3
B    1.6
C    1.8
D    1.0
```

I created a new table recordstable2 where I have put all value1, value2, value3 records to 0

```
recordtable2 
name  cat  value1  value2  value3 
jkl   A    0       0       0
jfu   A    0       0       0
eyr   B    0       0       0
...
```

Now I want to put a 1 for each time the value1 in recordtable is larger than the categorytable_value1 for each of the categories cat.

How can I do this?

```
recordtable2 
name  cat  value1  value2  value3 
jkl   A    0       0       0
jfu   A    1       0       0
eyr   B    1       0       0
...
```

(I will later do the same for value2, value3,... but i need to calculate the corresponding categorytable_value2,...)

Comment: Can't you put all the `categorytable_value*` tables into the same table? How are you planning to this per column? Eitherway, using `data.table` you could do something like `library(data.table) ; setDT(recordtable)[categorytable_value1, value1 := +(value1 > i.value), on = "cat"]` on your original data set.

Comment: You can also use a base R solution. `d1` is your recordtable and `c1` the categorytable_value1: `d2$value1 <- unlist(sapply(levels(d1$cat), function(x) ifelse(d1$value1[d1$cat == x] > c1$value[c1$cat == x],1,0)), use.names = F)`